# Why does my Player in Unity fall down when I start PlayMode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Video explanation](https://youtu.be/qfFVAu96s50)

My cube in Unity is falling down randomly.It is on a cube named "Ground" and it has a movement script attached below. Above is the video showing what happens, and I'll attach an image too. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubiik.png)

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 6f;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            controller.Move(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the colider covers the entire cube, because now it’s only of size 1 on all axis.[image]

Comment: @Breadatone if this solved your problem make sure to mark it as correct, for people with the same problem to know that there’s a solution to their problem.

Comment: Um, im new to stack overflow, how do i do that exactly?

Comment: Under the downvote and upvote thing there should be a check mark if you press it, it should turn green.

Comment: Oh, alright thanks!